# ipad application rejected due to only one orientation support

Tags: ipad, orientation

i developed first ipad application. i want to fix orientation to landscape. can i fix only one orientation to ipad application??

Answer (score 1):

Is there any *reason* for your application to only support one orientation, or is it just laziness on your part?

If the former (such as say, a game or similar), you'll just have to resubmit the app and hope for the best; maybe with some explanatory notes.

If the latter, you're just going to have to man up and restructure your interface to work with all orientations.

**Edit:** Vis-a-vis point one: Just because it's a game doesn't mean it only needs to support one orientation, but *some* games, e.g. driving simulators, are inherently landscape-only; but *only for the main game part of the application*.

Comment: Calling someone lazy is needlessly argumentative. Of course additional orientations requires additional coding, and can add to project complexity, particularly for games.

Comment: @SirRatty: When we're facing a person that cannot even be bothered to write structured sentences; I wouldn't call it *needlessly* argumentative.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike the iPhone Apple really wants iPad users to be able to hold the device at any orientation.  You are just going to have to support landscape and portrait orientations. Fortunately the screen is much closer to a square than the iPhone screen so you won't have to change to much.